# Zebra Wireless Printer Model Number

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Is there any way to query the printer for it's model number?  For example I want to distinguish between a QL420+, a QL320, and a QL320 plus.  It doesn't appear that there is either a ZPL or SGD to query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! U1 getvar "usb.device.product_string"

Comment: I was able to confirm that this works on the QL420+ model printer.  I started a telnet session with the printer and typed in the command provided in @banno answer and then flushed the output using Ctrl+O and the printer responded with "QL 420+"